# Function V2: Nuget package DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.8.1 encounter exception

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using the following:

- VS2017: 15.7.1
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions: 1.0.13
- Function Enviroment: V2

I'm installing the Nuget package DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.8.1 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml)
Running the function locally works fine. But when I publish it to Azure I'll get
`Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.` The system cannot find the file specified. Could not load the specified file.

Does anyone encounter the same issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could check the version of your function app in azure, is it `v2` ?

Comment: @JoyWang yes, it is V2, but I need to change version to 2.0.11651-alpha to avoid this issue

Comment: As the link you provided, the version 2.8.1 of DocumentFormat.OpenXml needs System.IO.Packaging (>= 4.4.0) in .net standard 1.3. So,you could try to upgrade your IO.Packaging verion.

Comment: i tried, but still get same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is caused by design for now. See [this github discussion](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/46#issuecomment-390275494).

> currently, redirecting/loading custom System.* assemblies is restricted. We do understand this is overly aggressive, and will relax that restriction in future updates, but that is by design with the initial implementation of the new assembly load behavior.

You can use `2.0.11651-alpha` on portal until [June 13th](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/106#issue-321777676), after then you may have to suspend this problem until the update releases.

**Update-6/13**

Runtime `2.0.11857` release is complete on Azure portal. This problem is fixed.
But it has not been available in VS. See [Release note](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases).

**Update-6/28**

New version `2.0.11888` has been available to VS.